# Eccentricity and Length of Semi Axes of a conic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

If a conic $ax^2+by^2+2hxy+2gx+2fy+c=0$ and say:

How to find the eccentricity and the semi-axes of this conic. I do understand that if its a hyperbola only one of the semi axes will be real.

Soham

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Identifying_rotated_conic_sections

Comment: hey thanks but I am not exactly sure, how it fits with the answer. The link talks about the equation in light of rotated axes, whereas I was looking more for eccentricity

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756220/how-to-find-centre-vertics-foci-focal-radii-letus-rectum-when-exists-of-a-gen/801572#801572