# How to find centre,vertics,foci,focal radii,letus rectum... when exists of a general quadratic equation in x and y

Tags: conic-sections

Is there a generalized way( a particular conic section of any shape,for instance an ellipse without determining its major/minor axis) to find the centre,vertices,foci,focal radii,letus rectum,eccentricity,etc when exists of any parabola,ellipse,hyperbola?(dealing separately)

$ax^2+by^2+cx+dy+exy+c=0$ ($a,b,c$ not all zero)

Comment: Well, I think you **first** must know whether the conic is a circle, parabola, hyperbola...and yes: there are ways to know this, in particular by means of linear algebra, matrices (signature, dterminant and stuff), etc.

Answer (score 7):

One can use a list of equations to determine the property you require.  Note, however, that in many cases it is easier to use derived value(s) as opposed to using equations that rely solely on the coefficients of the equation in general quadratic form.  Below are examples of equations one can use.

**Properties of an ellipse from equation for conic sections in general quadratic form**

Given the equation for conic sections in general quadratic form:

$ a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + c x + e y + f = 0 $

The equation represents an ellipse if:

$ b^2 - 4 a c < 0 $

or similarly,

$ 4 a c - b^2 > 0 $

The **coefficient normalizing factor** is given by:

$ q = 64 {{f (4 a c - b^2) - a e^2 + b d e - c d^2} \over {(4ac - b^2)^2}} $

The **distance between center and focal point** (either of the two) is given by:

$ s = {1 \over 4} \sqrt { |q| \sqrt { b^2 + (a - c)^2 }} $

The **semi-major axis length** is given by:

$ r_\max = {1 \over 8} \sqrt { 2 |q| {\sqrt{b^2 + (a - c)^2} - 2 q (a + c) }} $

The **semi-minor axis length** is given by:

$ r_\min = \sqrt {{r_\max}^2 - s^2} $

The **latus rectum** is given by:

$ l = 2 {{ {r_\min}^2 } \over {r_\max}} $

The **eccentricity** is given by:

$ g = {{s} \over {r_\max}} $

The **distance between center and closest directix point** (either of the two) is given by:

$ h = {{{r_\max}^2} \over {s}} $

The **center of the ellipse** is given by:

$ x_\Delta = { b e - 2 c d \over 4 a c - b^2} $

$ y_\Delta = { b d - 2 a e \over 4 a c - b^2} $

The **top-most point** on the ellipse is given by:

$ y_T = y_\Delta + {\sqrt {(2 b d - 4 a e)^2 + 4(4 a c - b^2)(d^2 - 4 a f)} \over {2(4 a c - b^2)}} $

$ x_T = {{-b y_T - d} \over {2 a}} $

The **bottom-most point** on the ellipse is given by:

$ y_B = y_\Delta - {\sqrt {(2 b d - 4 a e)^2 + 4(4 a c - b^2)(d^2 - 4 a f)} \over {2(4 a c - b^2)}} $

$ x_B = {{-b y_B - d} \over {2 a}} $

The **left-most point** on the ellipse is given by:

$ x_L = x_\Delta - {\sqrt {(2 b e - 4 c d)^2 + 4(4 a c - b^2)(e^2 - 4 c f)} \over {2(4 a c - b^2)}} $

$ y_L = {{-b x_L - e} \over {2 c}} $

The **right-most point** on the ellipse is given by:

$ x_R = x_\Delta + {\sqrt {(2 b e - 4 c d)^2 + 4(4 a c - b^2)(e^2 - 4 c f)} \over {2(4 a c - b^2)}} $

$ y_R = {{-b x_R - e} \over {2 c}} $

The **angle between x-axis and major axis** is given by:

if $ (q a - q c = 0) $ and $ (q b = 0) $ then $ \theta = 0 $ 
if $ (q a - q c = 0) $ and $ (q b > 0) $ then $ \theta = {1 \over 4} \pi $ 
if $ (q a - q c = 0) $ and $ (q b < 0) $ then $ \theta = {3 \over 4} \pi $ 
if $ (q a - q c > 0) $ and $ (q b >= 0) $ then $ \theta = {1 \over 2} {atan ({b \over {a - c}})} $ 
if $ (q a - q c > 0) $ and $ (q b < 0) $ then $ \theta = {1 \over 2} {atan ({b \over {a - c}})} + {\pi} $ 
if $ (q a - q c < 0) $ then $ \theta = {1 \over 2} {atan ({b \over {a - c}})} + {1 \over 2}{\pi} $

The **focal points** are given by:

$ F_{1,x} = x_\Delta - s \ cos (\theta) $

$ F_{1,y} = y_\Delta - s \ sin (\theta)) $

$ F_{2,x} = x_\Delta + s \ cos (\theta) $

$ F_{2,y} = y_\Delta + s \ sin (\theta)) $

(I tried to enter the equations without error.  If you find an error, please post a comment)

Comment: User R Nogueira claimed in a now-deleted answer that in the expression for $q$, the sign of the term $cd^2$ should be flipped. Symmetry considerations seem to back that up.

Comment: I fixed the mistake. Thank you for leaving a comment,